# Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Tags: yii2

Как исправить ошибку??

Это в Контролере:

```
        $cities = Profile::find()
        ->select('CONCAT(city_name, ", ",region_name) AS value')
        ->filterWhere(['like', 'city_name', $q])
        ->asArray()
        ->all();

    return Json::encode($cities);
```

А это ошибка в консоле браузера:

```
Exception (Database Exception) 'yii\db\Exception' with message 
'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an 
error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your 
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM `profile` 
WHERE `city_name` LIKE '%перв%'' at line 1
The SQL being executed was: SELECT CONCAT(city_name, `"`, `"`, 
`region_name)` AS `value` FROM `profile` WHERE `city_name` LIKE 
'%перв%''
```

Comment: попробуй убрать `", "` - оно ж не нужно ......для конкатенации с разделителем используется `CONCAT_WS` ............. ну и `select` возможно надо написать через квадратные скобки (но не факт) `->select(['concat(city_name,region_name) as value'])`

Comment: да так работает.....а как между city_name,region_name сделать запятую и пробел??

Comment: я не уверен на счет concat, но попробуй вместо двойных кавычек использовать одинарные (`', '`)...... но скорее всего, как я описал выше, нужно использовать `CONCAT_WS` - http://www.mysql.ru/docs/maryan/

Comment: спасибо тебе, все теперь правильно ['concat(city_name, ", ",region_name) as value']